# Cordova/Ionic reports Android SDK not found even though it's set | Arch Linux

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

k, so here's where I'm at:

```
$cordova run android --device
Running command: testapp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/user/testapp
add to body class: platform-android
Error: Android SDK not found. 
Make sure that it is installed. 
If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

heres what happens when I echo ANDROID_HOME:

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/patrick/Android/Sdk
```

Here's JAVA_HOME

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk
```

Here's PATH

```
/home/patrick/.cvm:
/home/patrick/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin:
/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:
/home/patrick/Android/Sdk/tools:
/home/patrick/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:
/home/patrick/Android/Sdk/build-tools:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/bin
```

After removing/re-adding the android platform I get:
    Your system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.2.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.10
Node Version: v6.2.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

I've also ran:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /home/patrick/.cordova
```

Comment: will this be any help ? 1)  export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk  (2)
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools

Comment: Tried those just now, still no go. -- if it helps I used CVM to install cordova. maybe try wiping that and using npm will work better?

Comment: That should work.. Just try it out